# TypeError: function got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python-3.x, django, api

Прошу не кидаться тапками, я еще только учусь.
Помогите разобраться
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
def add_ingredients_and_tags(self, tags, ingredients, recipe):
    for tag in tags:
        recipe.tags.add(tag)
        recipe.save()
    for ingredient in ingredients:
        IngredientAmount.objects.create(
            ingredien_id=ingredient.get('id'),
            amount=ingredient.get('amount'),
            recipe=recipe
        )
    return recipe


class IngredientRecipeGetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.id')
name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='ingredient.name')
measurement_unit = serializers.ReadOnlyField(
    source='ingredient.measurement_unit')

class Meta:
    model = IngredientAmount
    fields = ('id', 'name', 'amount', 'measurement_unit',)
```

Comment: Не добавляйте сообщение об ошибке в виде картинок. Скопируйте текст ошибки в вопрос (желательно целиком)